# Distinguish logical and structural/exception errors

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber

I am learning Ruby developement with Rspec and Cucumber. I have a hard time knowing when I have to switch from one to another. I know Rspec is used for logical errors while Cucumber, for structural/exceptions errors.

How can I know what type of error it gives? Is there a certain pattern of error reporting.

For example, `expected ...` is a logical error.

Comment: I use rspec for everything. So this problem doesn't exist for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber is usually used for acceptance tests, but under the hoods you're using Capybara steps for browser automation, which of course are available to Rspec too.

SO it's up to you. You can use either Cucumber for acceptance tests and Rspec for unit tests, or use Rspec for everything. I personally go with the latter, but it's really up to you. Try both, and see how it works for you.